# honeycomb - add custom button to taskbar

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

While in the application, is it possible to add a custom button to the taskbar thats displayed at the bottom of the screen (next to Home, windows buttons)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, you cannot add things to the system bar ("the taskbar thats displayed at the bottom of the screen") except for `Notifications`, and they appear on the far right.

Comment: Indeed, that's a big waste of space :-p

Comment: @Profete162: That may be true, but it will only be "a big waste of space" on tablets (and maybe televisions). From what I can tell, phones will not have the system bar, even on Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: Completely off topic, but you guess that the "full touch" interface and phone with no buttons was just a hoax?

Comment: @Profete162: It is possible that device manufacturers might have their choice of buttons or a system bar with ICS. We'll find out soon enough.